# Does grails support sharding?

Tags: grails, sharding

Does grails support sharding?

I want a multi-tenancy database solution and I looking at grails currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails ORM is built on Hibernate, so my guess is that it'll be capable of (or limited to) whatever Hibernate can do.  Hibernate Shards is the extension that supports sharding.  I haven't used it myself, but you might want to try plugging that in and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at: http://www.grails.org/plugin/sharding